# Namespace prefix disappeared after xslt transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I have created an xsl file to remove empty lines from a xml file.But because of it existing namespaces are get removed from the output xml.
Following is my xsl file.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need to keep all the namespaces as is.How should I change the xsl file to achive this.

Comment: Provide minimal but complete details to allow others to reproduce the problem. I don't think the XSLT code as shown can cause any disappearance of namespaces, unless there is a bug in your XSLT processor or the code you use to run the XSLT. So you need to provide more details to allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: Perhaps it's *redundant* namespace declarations that are disappearing? If you declare a namespace redundantly on both a parent element and one of its children, the duplicate declarations will be removed.